# Is following sentence grammatically correct.? They are my foundation

Tags: grammaticality

> They are my foundation.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you will see from the site guidelines, we like to help those who first help themselves. If you express your own research on the question and can then say where your difficulty lies, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: With '[NP“₁] is/are [NP₂]', whether copular inversion is claimed or not, the verb form always agrees with the fronted noun phrase. Of course, this may be notional agreement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Any chance you could rephrase your comment in plain English?

Comment: @Ronald Sole Sorry, this needs doctorate level analysis and corresponding references. I'm staggered it's been sent here. (1) In 'Jo is our president', 'Jo' is clearly the subject. But some grammarians claim that (2) in 'Our president is Jo' copular inversion has taken place and 'Jo' remains the subject. Whether or not this analysis is accepted, the verb still agrees with the noun phrase preceding it (subject or not!) So 'Bob and Ted are the problem' but 'The problem is Bob and Ted'. // 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast' still obeys this rule, with [bacon and eggs] notionally singular.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> They are my foundation.

contains no obvious grammatical error. But without more context its meaning is unclear, an it might even be incorrect, depending on the referent of "they".

Is "foundation" being used in a literal way, perhaps in an architectural sense? In that case "they" might refer to stones or other supporting elements. Or is it being used in a metaphorical way? Without context, there really isn't much to say about this sentence.